# How to interpret this jnettop output?

Tags: linux, ddos

Looks like I'm currently under a DOS attack or something like that, I've been monitoring the traffic on the server using jnettop, this is a of what I see during normal conditions:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/5qZXp.jpg

and this is an example of when the issue is happeing:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/4JjeX.jpg

SO my question is: what does that "IP" in protocol and also "0" in port means????

I replaced the ip of my server with: 1.1.1.1 to make it more readable. Of course this is just an entry of the output, in nomral operation the list has many more entries, and when I'm under the attack, also I see several entries with the same HUGE RX and 0 TX, so the solution is not just block that IP in the example.

Answer (score 1):

Could be that the attackers are using some exotic protocol on top of IP, that jnettop doesn't recognize.

You could try to use a network capture tool, with a filter such as `not tcp and not udp`, and see what remains.